# 0-1 sequence without spaces

Tags: r, sequence, spaces

Spaces are redundant when reporting a binary sequence. This code

```
x <- '1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 '
y<-gsub(' +', '', x)
```

does the job so I can copy and paste from R. How do I do the same for 0-1 sequences (and other one-digit data) in others formats, e.g.,

```
x <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
```

or

```
toString(x)
```

or whatever (for the sake of learning various options)? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For vectors, use the `paste()` function and specify the `collapse` argument:

```
x <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
paste( x, collapse = '' )

[1] "10000011010110"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
write.table(x,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,eol="\t")
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0
```

By changing the eol (end of line) character, you can decide if and what separator to use.